# django send request to self

Tags: python, django

There is two tries to get response from "working" django server. Working version is hardcoded and not working while unittesting

```
# working
# a = requests.post('http://localhost:8000/ImportKeys/',
#                   data=json.dumps({'user_id': key_obj.email,
#'key': self.restore_pubkey(key_obj.fingerprint)}))

# not working

a = requests.post('http://' + request.get_host() + reverse('import_keys'),data=json.dumps({'user_id': key_obj.email,'key': self.restore_pubkey(key_obj.fingerprint)}))
```

On that version, that I whant to starts working, I've got this(end stacktrace):

> File "/home/PycharmProjects/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 576, in send
>       r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
>     File "/home/PycharmProjects/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 437, in send
>       raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
>   requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='testserver', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /ImportKeys/ (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',))

And yes, I see that it's trying connect to 80 port, and this is bad.

Comment: Why send a request to self when you could just call the function? Is this for testing?

Comment: I'm plaining to move view 'import_keys' to separated service. And perhaps will be get result from external url.

But now, I just want to get result from my 'import_keys' view by url.

And in tests I got a problem.

Answer (score 1):

To test your views in the `TestCase` classes, use [`django.test.Client`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/testing/tools/#default-test-client), which is designed specifically for that purpose. If you inherit your test cases from `django.test.TestCase`, it's already available via the `self.client` attribute.

```
class YourTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_import_keys_posting(self):
        data = {
            'user_id': key_obj.email,
            'key': self.restore_pubkey(key_obj.fingerprint)
        }
        response = self.client.post(reverse('import_keys'), data)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertEqual(response.json(), {'result': 'ok'})
```

And if you use Django Rest Framework, consider using its wonderful [`APIClient`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#apiclient), which simplifies API testing even more.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to send requests to the server during tests (in that case this will probably not be from the test code itself but from some mock or from JS code):

Extend `LiveServerTestCase` instead `TestCase`. This will launch an actual server during tests.

If you are using `request.build_absolute_uri()` in your regular code which is being tested, you need to change the test code to update the HTTP request headers accordingly like this:

```
checkout_url = '{}{}'.format(self.live_server_url, reverse('checkout', kwargs={'pk': article.id}))
parsed_url = parse.urlparse(self.live_server_url)

# add the info on host and port to the http header to make subsequent
# request.build_absolute_uri() calls work
response = self.client.get(checkout_url, SERVER_NAME=parsed_url.hostname, SERVER_PORT=parsed_url.port)
```